# Can't see public leaderboard from google play

Tags: google-plus, public, game-center-leaderboard

This issue is bugging me for some time. Im using a plugin with google play services, and i'm missing the button that switch from public to circle leaderboard. this is not only on my apps, but every aps in my device. I did manage to see the button yesterday after upgrading to android lollipop, but its missing again!!!! I cant find any answer to this matter. if someone could shed light on this, it would be great! Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your leaderboard dosent support the android language you wont be able to see the "social-all" toggle, or the public leaderboard.

To fix this you must add the language to the service.
In the console, go to Game services, select your game,go to Game details,click on Manage translations and select Add translations.

Make sure you add Display name to each language you added.